# Exit application after click on android Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I've implemented a method that when my app is running in background a notification will be displayed on notification bar ..
Now I want to close app when I click on that notification :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 
                            (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Flashlight")
            .setContentText("turn off")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.light_on)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true).getNotification();
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, n);
} else {
    Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Flashlight")
            .setContentText("turn off")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.light_on)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, n);
}
```

How can I do this !?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "close app"?

Comment: @MikeM. I have no other activities in stack this is my only Activity running in background , after click I need to turn off my torch and then exit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to exit your app you can set an action for your intent , then create a Broadcast Receiver and finish your application inside onReceive method , then with IntentFilter receive your action , And register your receiver with action filter. Here is an example :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("close_app");
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, (int) 
                System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
.
.
.// build your notification
```

Then in your onCreate :

```
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Log.d("TAG" ,"onReceive ");
         finish();
       }
     };
```

Then receive your action and register in your onCreate or onResume:

```
      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
      filter.addAction("close_app");
      registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

And don't forget to unregister your receiver

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean to close the application or an activity?

Usually, an activity will be recycled if you do not use it for a long time.

If you want to kill the application, you can use this:

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid())
```

Comment: and how do i get my process id?